# Vue object properties not changing with v-bind:class

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a object which kind of looks like this:

```
{
    data: [
        {
            id: 28,
            type: "blabla",
            name: "myname",
            language: "en",
            active: true
        },
        {
            id: 5,
            type: "blabla",
            name: "myname2",
            language: "fr",
            active: false
        },
        // etc
    ]
}
```

I have split this object up into groups which I am display like this:

```
<li class="suggestion" v-for="suggestion in group">
    <a href="#" :class="{ active: suggestion.active }"></a>
</li>
```

I want to highlight my results so that is why I have a `position` property on my Vue object. which can be changed.

I have a watcher set up for the position attribute:

```
position() {
    this.suggestions.forEach((suggestion, index) => {
        suggestion.active = index === this.position;
    });
}
```

It will make the current position(so the currently item active). This works fine when I am checking the array of objects and their properties. The items change their `.active` property perfectly. But the class binding does not seem to re-evaluate.

What is going wrong here? The initial active state does get taken into account and my first item is highlighted perfectly fine.

Nothing happens on a change to the actual classes though yet with the Vue devtools I can see perfectly fine that the objects properties are changing.

Comment: I'm guessing vue does not do a deep watch. Since the property on the object got changed not the object itself. Vue will not re render it. You'll have to set up some watchers I guess.

Comment: @abhishekkannojia It is strange though that on the first run it does seem to evaulate the property though.

Comment: @Stephan-v so when you watch for position in that watcher do you change your data object or your group array?

Comment: @peaceman I change my data object. My group object is simply a computed property which groups my data object into categories.

Comment: @Stephan-v humor me and put a console log inside the body of that computed property. You are looking for a change after your data object is updated. If no log is written that we know where the problem is.

Comment: @peaceman My computed property reflects the changes perfectly inside the Vue devtools so it does not seem to go wrong there.

Comment: @Stephan-v are you sure `this.position` is a number and not a string?

Comment: @Stephan-v two suggestions. Try moving the body of your computed property to a method and loop over the data set you return from a method. Computed properties sometimes get cached. Second thing:  put {{ suggestion.active } in front of a tag. This will dump the data your loop actually shows. And I understand your Devtools is telling you one thing but something is obviously wrong here. I'm just trying to help.

Comment: @thanksd 100% sure it is a number.

Comment: @Stephan-v well, this fiddle works, maybe it can help you https://jsfiddle.net/qgesL76r/

Comment: @Stephan-v if you're still stuck, it's most likely because of the way you're defining your groups, could you show us that code?

Comment: This is the entirety of my component you are free to check it out but I don't expect you to find an answer for me: https://gist.github.com/stephan-v/690e99e76b5f7188b95570a8e9f19de7 Thanks for the help so far though, really appreciate it.

Comment: @Stephan-v I think you forfeit reactivity if you create stuff like this `object[suggestion.type].push(suggestion);` not because is bad but because Vue doesn't detect it. Try using Vue.set().

Comment: @peaceman I owe you a huge case of beer. I have changed my active property like so: https://gist.github.com/stephan-v/690e99e76b5f7188b95570a8e9f19de7/revisions and it works now. You are free to leave an answer for me to award points to since it helped me out a lot.

Comment: @Stephan-v :D I'm glad we could figure it out. I've had similar issues in the past so I like to help when a thing like this happens. Cheers. Thx for the beer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the problem was that if object gets created like this:

```
object[suggestion.type].push(suggestion);
```

Vue doesn't detect changes to that object. It has to do with how Vue watches objects for changes.

In order for Vue to play nicely with objects you create and want to be reactive you need to utilize [Vue.set](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html)

```
Vue.set(object, suggestion.type, suggestion)
```

Or

```
this.$set(object, suggestion.type, suggestion)
```